# Google's UrlShortener, where can I find the list

Tags: google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I shortened many URLs using Rest API, with 'API Project' which is one of my Google APIs projects.

However, I cannot find the list of shortened URLs in the page of https://goo.gl/.
(Here I can only find the list of shortened URLs I have created here on the webpage.)

I don't know why, but, I guess this is because I had several projects.

Where Can I find the list of shortened Urls with specific API-Key and project.

Plus, I cannot find it on the apis-explorer
(http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=ko#p/urlshortener/v1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API keys are used to access public APIs.  Google URL shortener is in fact a public API you don't need to be logged in in order to use it.

If you are not logged in then Google has no idea who it was that shortened said url and now way of keeping the stats for you that you are looking for.

If you want to keep the stats on your own page then you should change your application to use OAUTH2 authenticate your application then use that to shorten the URLs.   The stats will then apear.

Comment: Yes I used Oauth2 with my key. I will retrieve the list by using this Oauth2 key and tell you.

Comment: I dont think you understand.   You must create your Shortened URLs using the access token created by Oauth2.    Using an a public API key will not store the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I can shortenUrl with both APIkey and Oauth2 Token.

Comment: I can use the API(urlshortener.url.insert) with API-key only (without Oauth2 Token)

Comment: However, I cannnout use urlshortener.url.list with API-key. I think this is a problem. I cannot list my previous shortened urls. Is it right?

Comment: I should have shortened url using Oauth2 in the first place.. I am gonna lose all of my previous works for 3 months data

Comment: No your not going to loose it because it doesn't exist. Yes you should have used Oauth to begin

Comment: Code snippet that use both API Keys and OAuth2 for Google URL Shortener API you can checkout here for reference http://niralar.com/google-url-shortener-api-integration-nodejs/